# Validating Input in Batch File XY######## - Letters and Numbers Combination

Tags: validation, batch-file

I've created a batch/cmd file which executes correctly, but I would like to add a "validation" layer to check for correct input.

The input should be in the format of `LETTER-LETTER-########` (Eight Numbers)

I'm more of a Bash person myself so I'm a little lost.

Here is a basic version of what I am using.

```
echo Please Input like so XY########
set /P INPUT=Type input: %=%
```

Comment: This might help: https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5775

Comment: Downvotes without any comment as to how to improve are about as useful as keys you don't know what they lock.

Comment: @Squashman that looks promising, I didn't think it would be that complicated, but that looks doable.

Comment: well the balloon help for the down vote button does say "question does not show any research effort".

Comment: Isn't that what it says by default? (I never noticed that was there till now) It seems very generic.

Comment: Also, it's somewhat unclear what you're asking. The way I read your question right now, you want to get input from the user, but you want to ensure that whatever they entered is an eight-character alphanumeric. Is that correct?

Comment: _"I've created a batch/cmd file which executes correctly"_ Kindly Share this code, or the relevant portion of it, so I can at least see what your input looks like.

Comment: I would use [`findstr`](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) for input verification: `findstr /I "^[A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$"`

Comment: Thank you aschipfl and SomethingDark for the options, the dostips is cool because it stops user from inputting invalid data, but findstr was more what I wanted. I feel very unwelcome on this site after this post. Please read >> https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct >> If you’re here to help others, be patient and welcoming. 
Learning how to participate in our community can be hard. Offer support if you see someone struggling or otherwise in need of help.

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers: Yes. You should post your code, _any code_; otherwise, how we could help you? We all suppose that you want help _with code_. Isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Here we go...

There is no way to do what you want if you read the input via `set /P` command. In this case you may test the input afterwards and repeat it until be correct...

To check the input *at same time it is being typed* you need to read and test each character individually. There are several ways to do that. The simplest one is based on `choice` command:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

echo Please Input like so XY########
set /P "=Type input: " < NUL
set "INPUT="

rem Get two *UPPERCASE* letters
set "letter= ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
for /L %%i in (1,1,2) do (
   choice /C %letter% /N > NUL
   for %%l in ("!errorlevel!") do set "INPUT=!INPUT!!letter:~%%~l,1!"
   set /P "=!INPUT:~-1!" < NUL
)

rem Get eight digits
set "digit= 0123456789"
for /L %%i in (1,1,8) do (
   choice /C %digit% /N > NUL
   for %%l in ("!errorlevel!") do set "INPUT=!INPUT!!digit:~%%~l,1!"
   set /P "=!INPUT:~-1!" < NUL
)

echo/
echo INPUT = "%INPUT%"
```

In this code:

- Any letter pressed is converted to uppercase. This behavior may be cancelled including both upcase and lowcase letters in `letter` variable *and* adding `/CS` switch to `choice` command.
- The last character input can not be deleted.
- The input is automatically completed after the last character is input. No final ENTER key is needed.

If you want not this behavior and need more precise control on the input characters, then you must use another method; for example, reading the keys via `xcopy` trick. The link posted by Squashman above is an ample example on how to do that...

Comment: I just tested this, I love how it also forces valid input. Perhaps going forward I need to consider forcing valid input before I consider validating user input.

Comment: It even makes a little "beep" sound when user attempts to input incorrect characters.

Comment: I can't seem to copy and paste into the terminal when I run this code, any way to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Aacini's answer also forces valid user input vs validating retroactilvey, his answer is less code and more "readable" IMO. I will be using his answer, but I figured I'd share this method.

I asked to "retroactively" validate user input, but @Squashmans commented URL forces valid user input in the first place.

https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5775

Here is the "sanitized code" that I ended up with.

```
@echo off
@cls

::::START -- Section Blocks User from Inputting Invalid Data::::
setlocal
set "thisFile=%~F0"

call :ReadFormattedLine INPUT="__########" /M "Enter Input in Form XY########: "
echo/

:ReadFormattedLine var="mask" [/M "message"] [/P] [/F /W /A]

if "%~2" equ "" echo ERROR: Missing parameters & exit /B 1
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "var=%~1"
set "mask=%~2"
shift & shift
set "message="
if /I "%1" equ "/M" set "message=%~2" & shift & shift
set "password="
if /I "%1" equ "/P" set "password=1" & shift
set "switch=%~1"

set quote="
set "digit= 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 "
set "letter= A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z "
set "alphaNum=%digit%%letter%"
set "fmt=#_+?@"
set "show=$/\()[]:;,.- %digit: =%%letter: =%"
for /F %%a in ('copy /Z "%thisFile%" NUL') do set "CR=%%a"
for /F %%a in ('echo prompt $H ^| cmd') do set "BS=%%a" & set "SP=.%%a "

< NUL (
   set /P "=%message%"
   for /F "eol=| delims=" %%a in ('cmd /U /C echo !mask!^| find /V ""') do (
      if "!fmt:%%a=!" neq "%fmt%" (
         set /P "=Û"
      ) else if "%%a" neq " " (
         set /P "=%%a"
      ) else (
         set /P "=!SP!"
      )
   )
   set /P "=!SP!!CR!%message%"
)
set "input="
set /A i=0, key=0
goto checkFormat

:nextKey
   set "key="
   for /F "delims=" %%a in ('xcopy /W "%thisFile%" "%thisFile%" 2^>NUL') do if not defined key set "key=%%a"
   if "!key:~-1!" neq "!CR!" goto endif
      if /I "%switch%" equ "/A" goto nextKey
      if /I "%switch%" neq "/F" goto check/W
         :nextField
         set "format=!mask:~%i%,1!"
         if "%format%" equ "" goto endRead
         if "!fmt:%format%=!" equ "%fmt%" goto checkFormat
         set /P "=Û" < NUL
         set "input=%input% "
         set /A i+=1
         goto nextField
      :check/W
      if /I "%switch%" neq "/W" goto checkEmpty
         if %i% equ 0 goto endRead
         if "%format%" equ "" goto endRead
         goto nextKey
      :checkEmpty
      if %i% gtr 0 goto endRead
      goto nextKey
   :endif
   set "key=!key:~-1!"
   if "!key!" equ "!BS!" (
      if %i% gtr 0 (
         if "%format%" equ "" (
            set /P "=!SP!!BS!!BS!Û!BS!" < NUL
         ) else (
            set /P "=Û!BS!!BS!Û!BS!" < NUL
         )
         set "input=%input:~0,-1%"
         set /A i-=1
         if !i! equ 0 set key=0
      )
      goto checkFormat
   )
   if "%format%" equ "" goto nextKey
   if "!key!" equ "=" goto nextKey
   if "!key!" equ "!quote!" goto nextKey
   if "%format%" equ "#" ( rem Any digit
      if "!digit: %key% =!" equ "%digit%" goto nextKey
   ) else if "%format%" equ "_" ( rem Any letter
      if "!letter: %key% =!" equ "%letter%" goto nextKey
   ) else if "%format%" equ "+" ( rem Any letter, convert it to uppercase
      if "!letter: %key% =!" equ "%letter%" goto nextKey
      for %%a in (%letter%) do if /I "!key!" equ "%%a" set "key=%%a"
   ) else (
      rem Rest of formats are alphanumeric: ? @
      if "!alphaNum: %key% =!" equ "%alphaNum%" goto nextKey
      if "%format%" equ "@" ( rem Convert letters to uppercase
         for %%a in (%letter%) do if /I "!key!" equ "%%a" set "key=%%a"
      ) else if "%format%" neq "?" echo ERROR: Invalid format in mask: "%format%" & exit /B 2
      )
   )
   if defined password (
      set /P "=*" < NUL
   ) else (
      set /P "=%key%" < NUL
   )
   set "input=%input%%key%"

   :nextFormat
   set /A i+=1
   :checkFormat
   set "format=!mask:~%i%,1!"
   if "%format%" equ "" (
      if /I "%switch%" equ "/A" goto endRead
      if /I "%switch%" equ "/M" goto endRead
      goto nextKey
   )
   if "!show:%format%=!" neq "%show%" (
      if "!key!" equ "!BS!" (
         if "%format%" neq " " (
            set /P "=%format%!BS!!BS!Û!BS!" < NUL
         ) else (
            set /P "=!SP!!BS!!BS!Û!BS!" < NUL
         )
         set "input=%input:~0,-1%"
         set /A i-=1
         if !i! equ 0 set key=0
         goto checkFormat
      ) else (
         if "%format%" neq " " (
            set /P "=%format%" < NUL
         ) else (
            set /P "=!SP!" < NUL
         )
         set "input=%input%%format%"
         goto nextFormat
      )
   )
   if "%input:~-1%!key!" equ " !BS!" (
      set /P "=Û!BS!!BS!" < NUL
      set "input=%input:~0,-1%"
      set /A i-=1
      goto checkFormat
   )

goto nextKey
:endRead
echo/
endlocal & set "%var%=%input%"
echo %INPUT%
pause
exit /B
```